# How can I force jquery validator to trigger validation method even if form values are unchanged

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, forms, validation

I have a small aspx form, which I validate using jquery validator.

```
var validator = $('form').validate({
    invalidHandler: function (event, validator) {
        errorsCount.Count = errorsCount.Count + 1;
        if (errorsCount.Count >= 3) {
            window.location.replace("http://" + window.location.hostname + ":" + window.location.port + "/RequestError.aspx");
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        errorsCount.Count = 0;
        form.submit();
    },
    rules: {
        txtFirstName: {
            required: true,
            maxlength: 50,
            containsAlphaCharacter: true
        }
    },
    onkeyup: false,
    messages: {
        txtFirstName: {
            required: EnrollmentValidationMessages.English.REQUIRED_FIELD,
            maxlength: EnrollmentValidationMessages.English.MAX_STRING_LENGTH
        }
    }
});
```

With this setup, if I cause a validation error on any of the fields and hit the submit button, the method will run just fine. However, if I hit the submit button again, the method won't be run. This is what I need to work around. Basically I need the invalidHandler to run EVERY TIME user clicks on the button, regardless of form values being changed or not.

Comment: Call the `valid()` method. `$('form').valid()`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan OnClientClick??? I tried calling it there, but it does not help. It does not get fired every time. It acts the same as this code above.

Answer (score 0):

The jquery validator will cache the previous value once the form is submitted. Unless you change the value which is invalid or change any of the field's value in your form it will not submit.

To force jquery validator to revalidate again without changing the field value, you have to remove the previously cached value from the jquery validator.

To do this, place this line of code on the top, before calling the validator.

```
$("#form :input").removeData("previousValue");
```

or if you want to remove only the specific value then,

```
$("#txtFirstName").removeData("previousValue");
```

This will work.